# application monitor the server room

Tags: php, monitoring, snmp

I want to develop a web application to monitor the server room (detect Humidity, Temperature and Flooding) can you give me some ideas or documentations about this, Thank you

Answer (score 4):

[Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) is pretty much the standard for anything like this. Handily enough, they sell [the sensors too](http://www.nagios.org/products/environmental/esensors). If you'd like your own app, you could always use their sensors and build your own frontend with rrdtool or something.

Answer (score 3):

A web application by itself will not be able to do that. I used to work on a similar project for server monitoring. You will need some sort of a backend providing the data. The backend pulls/collects the data, the web site presents the data.

If you have a database with up-to-date monitoring data or an interface with snmp/XML you can query your good to go. Then you can write a website with php that collects the data whenever you refresh the webpage.